# How is the creation of a console interface when creating console application done behind the scenes?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line-interface

As far as I know someone should create the console interface and provide the interaction but how is this done when I write a C++ console app for example? Is some code to do this added to the executable? I am talking about Windows OS.

Comment: You *can* create a console manually if you need to.  But for an ordinary console application, Windows does it for you.  You don't need to write any code, just make sure you use the right build settings.

Comment: Where can I find more information about how it's done? I've been reading the documentation about Consoles ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010(v=vs.85).aspx ) but it doesn't provide such info. Also, what do you mean by providing 'right build settings' ? And, when the compiler is creating the executable, does it do anything about this (to tell windows I want a console, etc)?

Comment: Yes, the build tools have to include this information when building the executable's header.  If you're using Microsoft's build tools, this is determined by the [`/SUBSYSTEM` linker option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx).  A console application uses the CONSOLE subsystem; a GUI application uses the WINDOWS subsystem.

Comment: What about gcc? And where can I learn more about the whole thing? Any resources. Thank you a lot.